# Django - Login required for specific user type

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, abstractuser

I extended the user login from Django with AbstractUser like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
class Seller(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    money = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)
```

I would like now to create a view and a form that can only be access by the "Seller" user, like this in views.py:

```
@login_required
def account(request):
    return render(request= request,
               template_name='main/account.html',
               context = {})
```

Any idea on how can I do it? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`@user_passes_test`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def is_seller(user):
    try:
        return user.is_authenticated and user.seller is not None
    except Seller.DoesNotExist:
        return False

@user_passes_test(is_seller)
def account(request):
    # …
```

This will only allow users that are authenticated, and for which the related `Seller` object exists.

Comment: It did work. I would like to ask a question anyway, just to make sure. In case that the user is not a "Seller", or not a logged in user at all, when I try to access that page I get a (404) error. Is that how it should be ?

Thank you very much so far, Willem

Comment: @ÁlvaroValero: it will normally aim to redirect to the `login_url`, but if you did not set one, then it will likely indeed respond with a 404.